# How to remove sign up option from ngx-admin login page

Tags: angular6, ngx-admin

There is an sign up option on login page. But i don't want to provide sign up option on login page. I want to provide a feature where only admin can create new account. For that i want to remove the sign up option from login page. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code at

> ngx-admin-master/src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss

```
.another-action {   display: none !important; }
```

Comment: :( no impact, Still the same issue.

Comment: i have just fork the ngx-admin template and tried it it works for me can you please share the version of @nebular/auth you are using at you package.json filee

Answer (score -1):

use

```css
.another-action{
    display:none
  }
```

in index.html under style will work

Comment: No impact, still the same.